# Why does the answer differ when taking log to differentiate

Tags: derivatives

The question is to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ of $xy=e^{x-y}$

when differentiating both sides directly I get $$\frac{e^{x-y}-y}{x+e^{x-y}}$$

But when first taking log on both sides and doing the same I get y' do be :$$\frac{y(x-1)}{x(1+y)}$$

What went wrong in the first method cause the latter is given to be the answer.

Comment: If we can't see the steps you took, how can we know what went wrong?

Comment: It's better to write all of your work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replacing $e^{x-y} =xy$ in the first gives the second expression.